# Is there a foundation of mathematical logic?

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, foundations, laws-of-physics

As Mathematics has its foundations in logic and set theory in the sense that you can derive all of mathematics from such theories, does mathematical physics have such foundations? A theory or theories such that from those theories you can derive all of physics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87239/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There are axioms (like Wightman and Osterwalder-Schrader) for certain mathematical structures that physicists like to use. But any result you derive from them will stay mathematical until it's held accountable. You might see exact matching to data in all regimes you've checked but there will always be some regime we haven't checked. So any attempt to give your theory a checkmark which says "this is the way it actually works" (as Wolfram and Weinstein like to do) will always be premature.